# DB of GPS Point in APK, is there any way?

Tags: applications, adb

I want to extract DB of GPS location in APK. I decompiled the APK and open DBM.Java File as follows:

```
   public DBM open() {
    return open(this.databasePath);
}

public DBM open(String path) {
    try {
        if (!path.endsWith(SQLITE_EXTENTION) && SamaUtils.absoluteFileExist(AppViewer.getContext(), path + SQLITE_EXTENTION)) {
            path = path + SQLITE_EXTENTION;
        }
        this.portalDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 268435456);
        return this;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

How I can extract the DB of GPS Location in this APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excerpt of decompiled code you've pasted isn't sufficient to know the exact path to the database, because it doesn't give the value of `this.databasePath`, but no matter. The file will be stored somewhere in the app's private data, so after you've rooted your phone, just look in `/data/data/packagename` where `packagename` is the package name of this app. There will be an SQLite database file in there somewhere. The constant `SQLITE_EXTENTION` in the code you've decompiled but not included will tell you the extension to look for: it's probably `.sqlite_db`.

Don't forget you'll need a rooted phone to access the file.